# NGINX CSS Not Loading

Tags: nginx, xenforo

I just set up my new vps to hold my website server. It works perfectly fine on my existing vps, but after I put it on the new one, none of the CSS files are loading.

Image here: [image]

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `server` block in there has to be location for static files:

```
server {
    server_name yourhost.com www.yourhost.com;
    root /var/www/vhosts/yourhost.com/public/;
    ... 

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/yourhost.com/public/static;
    }
}
```

So that

```
    location /static {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/yourhost.com/public/static;
    }
```

has to be properly configured, pointing to the location where your static files are placed.

Then if your css is in file `styles.css` (or any other file) and is placed on the server as `/var/www/vhosts/yourhost.com/public/static/css/styles.css`, it will be accessible from `/static/css/styles.css` in your html.

To see where exactly this is configured, you can start with `nginx.conf` (normally in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`) and check what other conf files are imported.

Note the path provided is fully up to you, but once it's known it has to be properly configured with the alias in the static location.

Comment: This can't be the issue as with my last dedicated server, it worked all fine without the static location, i am using the exact same files for my domain which doesn't contain the static. I can't do that either because of xenforo